# python lists, appending something to the list changes the entire thing?

Tags: python, list

so im trying to implement selection sort in python.. and im appending the result of each iteration to a list to print at the end.. my code sorts the list of numbers properly but when i append it to the same list at the end it changes all other lists..

```
def s_sort(numbers):
  alist=[]
  #do actual sorting here and swap numbers/index if neccessary

       alist.append(numbers)
  return alist

def main():
    numbers=[5,7,3]
    print(s_sort(numbers))
main()
```

the alist returned is [[3,5,7],[3,5,7]] instead of [[3,7,5],[3,5,7]] !!!!
somehow when i do the append to alist, the content of alist changes for both lists!

Comment: You don't have a list of two lists, you have a list of two copies of the same list. Since you've given us a fragment of code that doesn't run and wouldn't return what you said it does if fixed to run, it's hard to explain why your actual code does that.

Comment: You should see the concept of shallow copy and deep copy of lists in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a slice to make a copy

```
newlist = alist[:]
```

In your case, I guess it's:

```
alist.append(numbers[:])
```

Comment: i understand why it was doing that now lol.. making a copy of the list solved it! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the actual sort that you're doing, but in general:

Lists are mutable. Any change you make to it affects all links to that list. To make a copy of it and break its connection to other references, you need to `return alist[:]`

```
def s_sort(numbers):
  alist=[]
  #do actual sorting here and swap numbers/index if neccessary

       alist.append(numbers)
  return alist[:]  # this makes it a copy!

def main():
    numbers=[5,7,3]
    print(s_sort(numbers))
main()
```

Comment: ahh forgot lists were mutable in python :S thnx!

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't actually do what you say it does. In fact, it doesn't even run. But here's a simple example that does demonstrate the problem you're seeing:

```
def s_sort(numbers):
    alist=[]
    alist.append(numbers)
    numbers.sort()
    alist.append(numbers)
    return alist
```

The problem is that `alist` is not a list of two different lists, it's a list of the same list twice in a row. So, when you modify that one list, of course that one list is modified everywhere it appears—in `numbers`, and in `alist[0]`, and in `alist[1]`.

The solution is to not add the same list multiple times; instead, add a new one. For example:

```
def s_sort(numbers):
    alist=[]
    alist.append(numbers[:])
    alist.append(sorted(numbers))
    return alist
```

Now you've created two brand-new lists—one an exact copy of the original, one a sorted copy—and returned a list of them.

So, instead of returning `[[3, 5, 7], [3, 5, 7]]` (and also changing `numbers` to be `[3, 5, 7]`), it returns `[[5, 7, 3], [3, 5, 7]]` (and leaves `numbers` alone).

I have no idea why you expected `[3, 7, 5]` for the first element, but maybe you're doing some other work to the first element of `alist` which you didn't show us. In which case, as long as you do that work in a copying rather than mutating way (ala `sorted(n)` vs. `n.sort()`) or do it to a copy, everything will be fine.